# Does a map task read its input data in parallel?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Assume the replication factor of HDFS is 3, so for a map task there are three nodes holding its input data. Does the map task read from all 3 nodes in parallel or randomly pick one of them?

I have done some experiment where I set one of data nodes to have a very low bandwidth and get some extremely slow map tasks, so I guess a map task doesn't read from all available data node in parallel, am I right?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your replication factor is 3, there are three nodes in the cluster which hold the input data for a particular map task.

The Job Tracker will assign a map task to only one of these three nodes, so it only reads data from that node.

Hadoop has a feature called speculative execution. In speculative execution, if the Job Tracker finds that one of the map tasks is taking too long to complete, it will start the same map task on another node where the data is available. The data sent to reducer is taken from whichever map task completes first. In this case you will have 2 map tasks reading the same input data, but on different nodes.

Comment: Note that the JobTracker can assign a task to a node which doesn't host a local copy of the block(s) being processed - you'll see this in the counters Data Local (a number less than the number of map tasks indicated non data locality of 1 or more jobs) and Rack Local (where the data block isn't local to the map task, but is on the same rack in the network topology)

Answer (score 1):

The mapper task will execute on one of the Task Tracker node and will read the block from one of the Data Node (local or remote).